# MongoDB reusable custom javascript module

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

I would like to create a local Javascript module I can "require" in other files to handle all MongoDB CRUD operations.
I wrote something as:

-- dbConn.js file --

```
require('dotenv').config()
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

let _connection

const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
        return client 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(error)
    }

}

exports.findOne = async () => {

    let client = await connectDB()

    if (!client) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        const db = client.db("Test_DB");
        const collection = db.collection('IoT_data_Coll');
        const query = {}
        let res = await collection.findOne(query);
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }


   }

exports.findAll = async () => {

    let client = await connectDB()

    if (!client) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        const db = client.db("Test_DB");
        const collection = db.collection('IoT_data_Coll');
        const query = {}
        let res = await collection.find(query).toArray();
        return res;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Then in another file (not necessary inside Express app), say

-- app.js ---

```
const findAll = require('./dbConn').findAll
const findOne = require('./dbConn').findOne

findAll().then(res => JSON.stringify(console.log(res)))
findOne().then(res => JSON.stringify(console.log(res)))
```

I wonder if it is correct?
I have to close the connection after each method/CRUD operation?

I was trying to use IIF instead of ".then", as:

```
(async () => {
    console.log(await findOne())
})()
```

But I receive a weird error saying that findAll is not a function.
What's wrong with it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your use case which isn’t clear If you are using Express or just stand alone and how frequent are you planning to run app.js

Either way your code is expensive, each time you reference dbCon.js you are opening a new connection to the database.

So you can fix app.js by only requiring dbCon.js once and use it..

The best practice is to ofcourse use connection pooling https://www.compose.com/articles/connection-pooling-with-mongodb/